# How to select the underneath object hidden under another one in Krita?

Tags: selections, krita

I have a “sandwich” of objects in a vector layer in Krita, one over the other. I am not able to select the desired object with the “Select Shapes Tool”

- neither by *clicking* on it,
- nor by *dragging a rectangle* over it

  - neither *from left to right* (the blue rectangle),
  - nor from *right to left* (the green rectangle).

The selection always contains more than 1 object.

Is there a way to select the desired object from such a sandwich?

(I didn't find any word about it in the Krita's manual.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select *one* object from the overlapped set, just

- hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, and
- repeatedly click on the “sandwich” of them.

Every click will select the next object beneath the cursor, cycling between all of them.